# Unable to create a record in except loop of try-except odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

When i call the below function through API;
In both try and except conditions I have to keep log in separate table named api.log.
While the function enters in except condition, error occurs on creating record on api.log table

Comment: The terminal shows this error:

InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
@http.route('/tax_master',type="json",methodn ['POST'],auth="public",csrf=Falenter code herese)
def create_tax_master(self,**kw):
    kw = http.request.params
    obj_tax_master = request.env['tax.master']
    obj_account_tax = request.env['account.tax']
    flag = kw.get('flag')
    vals = {}
    result = False
    if kw.get('name'):
        vals['name'] = kw.get('name')
    if kw.get('value'):
        vals['value'] = kw.get('value')
    if kw.get('scope'):
        vals['scope'] = kw.get('scope')
    if kw.get('is_excise'):
        vals['is_excise'] = kw.get('is_excise')
    if kw.get('description'):
        vals['description'] = kw.get('description')
    if kw.get('amount_type'):
        vals['amount_type']= kw.get('amount_type')
    if 'is_excise' in kw and kw.get('is_excise') not in [1,0]:
        result = json.dumps({
                            "statusCode":02,
                            "statusDesc":"The value for the field is_excise should be 0 or 1"})
    try:
        if flag == 'create':
            tax_id = obj_tax_master.sudo().create(vals).id
            result = json.dumps({"id":tax_id,
                            "statusCode":01,
                            "statusDesc":"Successfully Created"
                            })
        elif flag == 'write':
            if kw.get('id'):
                tax_id_rec = obj_tax_master.sudo().browse([int(kw.get('id'))])
                if tax_id_rec.active == False:
                    result = json.dumps({
                        'statusCode': 02,
                        'statusDesc': 'The Tax is Archived.Updation is not possible now',
                    })
                else:
                    tax_id_rec.sudo().write(vals)
                    tax_id = kw.get('id')
                    result = json.dumps({"id":tax_id,
                                "statusCode":01,
                                "statusDesc":"Successfully Updated"
                                })
            else:
                result = json.dumps({
                    'statusCode' : 02,
                    'statusDesc' : 'Please provide valid id to update the record',
                })

        elif flag == 'delete':
            tax_id = obj_tax_master.sudo().browse(int(kw.get('id')))
            if tax_id.active == False:
                result = json.dumps({
                    'statusCode': 02,
                    'statusDesc': 'The record is already archived!!!',
                })
            else:
                tax_id.write({'active':False})
                taxes = obj_account_tax.sudo().search([('tax_master_id','=',kw.get('id'))])
                for tax in taxes:
                    tax.write({'active':False})
                result = json.dumps({
                    'statusCode' : 01,
                    'statusDesc' : 'The record is archived successfully!!!',
                })
        data = json.loads(result)
        self.create_api_log('tax_master', flag, kw, data)
        return data
    except Exception,e:
        result = json.dumps({'statusCode' : 02,'statusDesc' : str(e),})
        data = json.loads(result)
        self.create_api_log('tax_master', flag, kw, data)
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by using commit function.